# Remove dot character from a String C#

Tags: c#

Assume I have a string "2.36" and I want it trimmed to "236"

I used Trim function in example

```
String amount = "2.36";
String trimmedAmount = amount.Trim('.');
```

The value of trimmedAmount is still 2.36

When `amount.Trim('6');` it works perfectly but with '.'

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot
Cheers

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Trimming is removing characters from the start or end of a string.

You are simply trying to remove the `.`, which can be done by [replacing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) that character with nothing:

```
string cleanAmount = amount.Replace(".", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to remove everything but the digits:

```
String trimmedAmount = new String(amount.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

or:

```
String trimmedAmount = Regex.Replace(amount, @"\D+", String.Empty);
```

Comment: +1 for providing a alternative answers, but both of them are slower than the accepted one.

Comment: @Yogu: Yes, if you only want to remove one specific character, `Replace` is faster.

Answer (score 5):

`String.Trim` removes leading and trailing whitespace.  You need to use `String.Replace()`

Like:

```
string amount = "2.36"; 
string newAmount = amount.Replace(".", "");
```

Comment: `Trim` can take a `char[]` parameter that will trim all leading and trailing characters that are present in the passed in array.

Comment: So it can.  That will be useful in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Two ways :

```
string sRaw = "5.32";
string sClean = sRaw.Replace(".", "");
```

Trim is make for removing leading and trailings characters (such as space by default).